# Cocos2d-x rendering box2d objects with existing images

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to apply texture to box2d object in cocos2d-x, but I want to use my own images..
For a single b2body I can do that but for filling b2EdgeShape with my own images I need help..
Whats the best way for that....
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you should take a look at this: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/52726

This is a simple example and the author provides the source too.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to create something like in Hill Climb, the ground part exactly like that..

Comment: @so a parallax scroller?

Comment: no not parallax, in Hill Climb they use some texture to render the ground part, I am asking for that how they an external texture on the ground. I have created the ground like that by using b2EdgeShape but I am unable to render the texture on that ongoing path. please help